# Flex: how do I reset an attribute like `width` or `height` to default?

Tags: apache-flex, layout, attributes, flex3, default

I have a component:

```
<mx:List width="100%" height="100%" />
```

and that works out for nearly all uses of this component, except one. I want to have `height` remain default in one usage.

According to Adobe's manual, the default is 0, but

```
<mystuff:myList height="0" />
```

doesn't work and

```
<mystuff:myList height="0%" />
```

is an improvement, but still not the same as having a `<mx:List />` w/no height specified at all.

I'm using the Flex 3.5 SDK.

Comment: What does it mean for a list to have a height of 0?  It means you can't see the list.  Why not just leave the height be and set alpha to 0 for this particular case?  Or remove the list from its parent (and add it back later when you have something to display)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve by using the "default" sizing, but you could try setting the height to NaN.

```
<mystuff:myList height="NaN" />
```

Comment: Let's just say that my project isn't my own, and if I go around refactoring stuff and am not very very sure that I'm not affecting anything I shouldn't, I open myself up to some serious hurt.

Your solution worked. Thanks.